# Passing value from Groovy script to DataSync in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a script that loops through a dataset X and for each record in that dataset X loops in another dataset Y and retrieves some results.  How can I pass those results to a DataSink?

A number of suggestions around have been to use properties however in my groovy script I have a loop within which i receive the results and if i populate a property with every result i guess i will only be able to see the last result in the property, and my DataSink will only find the last result.

My code below:

```
def goodWeather = context.expand( '${#TestCase#goodWeather}' ) as String

if (goodWeather.equals("false"))
{
  def response = context.expand( '${CityWeatherRequest#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://tempuri.org/\'; //ns1:GetCityWeatherResponse[1]/ns1:GetCityWeatherResult[1]/ns1:Weather[1]}' )
  def cityinfo_City = context.expand( '${GetCitiesDS#cityinfo_City}' )
  def cityinfo_Country = context.expand( '${GetCitiesDS#cityinfo_Country}' )

  //Keep count to restrict number of returns.  CountSuggestedCities is a property.
  def count = context.expand( '${#TestCase#countSuggestedCities}' ) as Integer
  assert count instanceof Integer

  //Suggest some cities if skies are clear
  if (response.contains("clear sky"))
  {  
    if (count == 0) log.info("Making suggestions")  
    count ++
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("countSuggestedCities", count.toString()); 
        log.info(cityinfo_City + " located in: " + cityinfo_Country);
  }

  //Check property maxSuggestedCities to see if maximum suggestes required as been reached.
  if (count == (context.expand( '${#TestCase#maxSuggestedCities}' ) as Integer))
  {
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("countSuggestedCities", "0");  
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("goodWeather", "true");
    testRunner.gotoStepByName("SeperatorScript");
  }
}
else
{
    testRunner.gotoStepByName("SeperatorScript");
}
```

What I want is to replace `log.info(cityinfo_City + " located in: " + cityinfo_Country);` with saving that information to a database using a DataSink.

Comment: Hi @aristotll I'm using mysql driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the soapui doc provides examples about DataSink with groovy and database.  But you can always use [Groovy sql](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute-java.lang.String-java.util.List-) to do the insertion. Here is the example code:

```
def driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(driverName)
def user = "root" // change this , password, and jdbc url
def password = ""
def con = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_for_so",
        user, password, driverName)
def cityinfo_City = 'London'
def cityinfo_Country = 'England'
con.execute("INSERT INTO cityinfo (cityinfo_City, cityinfo_Country) VALUES (?, ?)",
        [cityinfo_City, cityinfo_Country])
con.close()
```

Comment: Yep thanks @aristotll, I did it as you suggested, could not find a way to do what I wanted via DataSink which i found strange.